# CloudKitty did not display price while creating instance, and trigger ERROR info under Start Command

Tags: python, openstack

**CloudKitty Version**: commit 35ce237b763407e7844545d5e2531c6dc0f15998 (HEAD -> master, origin/master, origin/HEAD) Author: Rafael Weingärtner rafael@apache.org Date: Tue Jun 22 09:48:13 2021 -0300

**Steps to reproduce**:

1. Using DevStack installed OpenStack with CloudKitty and Ceilometer
   releated compont
2. Using Dashboard enabled CloudKitty hashmap module
3. Using Dashboard defined the cost of instance, contains flavor_id
   field. Run "cloudkitty-processor --config-file
   /etc/cloudkitty/cloudkitty.conf"
4. Using Dashboard create and luanch
   instance, repeatedly click "Price"/"Flavor"/"Networks"

Result in command line:

2021-07-01 10:54:46.883 17862 DEBUG cloudkitty.orchestrator [-] Received quote from RPC. quote /opt/stack/cloudkitty/cloudkitty/orchestrator.py:118

2021-07-01 10:54:46.883 17862 DEBUG cloudkitty.orchestrator [-] Chris Received Data3:**[{'usage': {'instance': [{'desc': {'flavor_name': 'cirros256', 'flavor_id': 'c1', 'vcpus': 1, 'disk': 1, 'ephemeral': 0, 'disk_total': 1, 'disk_total_display': 1, 'ram': 256, 'source_type': 'image', 'source_val': '47cdc39d-935b-44c6-8810-8688e5b0b1b2', 'image_id': '47cdc39d-935b-44c6-8810-8688e5b0b1b2'}, 'vol': {'qty': '1', 'unit': 'undef'}}]}}]** quote /opt/stack/cloudkitty/cloudkitty/orchestrator.py:119

2021-07-01 10:54:47.039 17862 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.server [-] Exception during message handling: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'start'

2021-07-01 10:54:47.039 17862 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.server Traceback (most recent call last):

2021-07-01 10:54:47.039 17862 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.server File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/oslo_messaging/rpc/server.py", line 165, in _process_incoming

2021-07-01 10:54:47.039 17862 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.server res = self.dispatcher.dispatch(message)

2021-07-01 10:54:47.039 17862 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.server File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/oslo_messaging/rpc/dispatcher.py", line 309, in dispatch

2021-07-01 10:54:47.039 17862 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.server return self._do_dispatch(endpoint, method, ctxt, args)

2021-07-01 10:54:47.039 17862 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.server File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/oslo_messaging/rpc/dispatcher.py", line 229, in _do_dispatch

2021-07-01 10:54:47.039 17862 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.server result = func(ctxt, **new_args)

2021-07-01 10:54:47.039 17862 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.server File "/opt/stack/cloudkitty/cloudkitty/orchestrator.py", line 121, in quote

2021-07-01 10:54:47.039 17862 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.server return str(worker.quote(res_data))

2021-07-01 10:54:47.039 17862 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.server File "/opt/stack/cloudkitty/cloudkitty/orchestrator.py", line 224, in quote

2021-07-01 10:54:47.039 17862 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.server processor.obj.quote(res_data)

2021-07-01 10:54:47.039 17862 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.server File "/opt/stack/cloudkitty/cloudkitty/rating/init.py", line 106, in quote

2021-07-01 10:54:47.039 17862 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.server return self.process(data)

2021-07-01 10:54:47.039 17862 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.server File "/opt/stack/cloudkitty/cloudkitty/rating/hash/init.py", line 262, in process

2021-07-01 10:54:47.039 17862 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.server output = dataframe.DataFrame(start=data.start, end=data.end)

2021-07-01 10:54:47.039 17862 **ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.server AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'start'**

The second line of above console debug info is the Log of the debugging code I added myself，shows that there is indeed no Start property in the List.
This issue has been reported to OpenStack official website,but nobody reply.  https://storyboard.openstack.org/#!/story/2009022

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I think Cloudkitty launched the 2.0 version 2 years ago. Maybe the predictive pricing only worked in version 1.0.
I could reproduce the same bug in Devstack and Kolla Ansible.
Also, Rafael replied your question in the Storyboard.
From now on, I recommend you to post your bugs in the Storyboards, as is the official site to do it for Openstack.